# Update list item in material ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a project in react, and I'm building a simple todo app.  When an item in the list is clicked, I want to update the value.  My code looks like this:

```
export default function ShowTodos () {

  const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState<ITodo[]>([]);

  const [selectedTodo, setSelectedTodo] = React.useState<ITodo>({});

  const [dialogState, setDialogState] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

  const confirm = useConfirm();



  useEffect(() => {

      getTodos()
      .then(({data: {todos}}: ITodo[] | any) => {
        const todoList = todos
       setTodos(todoList)
      })
      .catch((err: Error) => console.log(err))


  })


  const handleConfirmation = (id: string) => {

    confirm({ description: 'This action is permanent!' })
    .then(() => { deleteTodoById(id).then(r => )})
  }



  return (
      <List>
        {todos.map((todo: ITodo ) =>
            (
              <ListItem onClick={() => {
                console.log("hh", todo);
                setDialogState(!dialogState)
              }
              } key={todo._id}>
                <ListItemText
                    primary={todo.text}
                />
                  <IconButton edge="end" aria-label="delete" onClick={() => handleConfirmation(todo._id)}>
                    <DeleteIcon />
                  </IconButton>

            <Dialog open={dialogState} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
              <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Update</DialogTitle>
              <DialogContent>
                <TextField
                    defaultValue={todo.text}
                    autoFocus
                    margin="dense"
                    id="name"
                    fullWidth
                />
              </DialogContent>
              <DialogActions>
                <Button color="primary" onClick={() => setDialogState(false)}>
                  Cancel
                </Button>
                <Button  color="primary" onClick={() => updateTodo(selectedTodo)}>
                  Update
                </Button>
              </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
              </ListItem>
            )
        )}
      </List>
  );

}
```

However the odd thing is that the defaultValue when the item is clicked is always the last item in the list.  How am I to change it to be the text of the item clicked?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need separate state of each todo item to new Component

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in this piece of code:

```
<ListItem onClick={() => {
            console.log("hh", todo);
            setDialogState(!dialogState)
          }
          } key={todo._id}>
```

onClick you toggling dialog, but not specify selectedTodo.

try something like that:

```
onClick={() => {
            console.log("hh", todo);
            setSelectedTodo(todo);
            setDialogState(!dialogState);
          }
```

and I guess you should define `updateTodo`